# Почему при обмене данных клиент/сервер на python, сервер обменивается с клиентом через порт 52086, хотя задан порт 80?

Tags: python, сеть

Вот мой код:

## client.py

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 80
s.connect((host, port))
response = s.recv(1024)
print("Received data from {0}:{1}:\n{2}".format(host, port, response.decode()))
s.close()
input("Press any key to continue...")
```

## server.py

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 80
s.bind((host, port))
print("Listening on port 80...")
s.listen(5)
while True:
  c, addr = s.accept()
  print("Accepted connection from: ", addr)
  c.send(b"Hello, Client!")
  c.close()
```

## Вывод client.py

```
Received data from 127.0.0.1:80:
Hello, Client!
Press any key to continue...
```

## Вывод server.py

```
Listening on port 80...
Accepted connection from: ("127.0.0.1", 52086)
```

Comment: Потому что порт клиента и порт сервера - это разные порты. Порт клиента всегда случайный, это нормально

Comment: Большое спасибо! А то это вызывало некоторые вопросы.

Answer (score 2):

Есть исходящий порт и входящий (listening). Сервер ожидает подключения на 127.0.0.1:80, а клиент подключается с порта 127.0.0.1:52086.